# jQuery UI Datepicker number of months

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

Does anybody know if its possible to change the number of months shown on the jQuery UI Datepicker from displaying two months on Desktop to one month on mobile devices.

I've had a look through the jQuery UI Datepicker options but cant seem to find the answer I'm looking for.

What I am trying to achieve is something simiar to http://www.lastminute.com/ datepicker options.

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-numberOfMonths

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35847066/how-to-change-jquery-datepicker-number-of-months-dynamically-responsive

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`numberOfMonths`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-numberOfMonths) option it's the number of months to show at once.

According to a feature detection/media query you can reduce the value on mobile browsers.

Code:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 2
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/4aj9u9sc/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker-3").datepicker({
        appendText:"(yy-mm-dd)",
        dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd",
        numberOfMonths: 2

    });
});
```

and in HTML side

```
 <p>Enter Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker-3"></p>
```

But Before That you have to extend :

- jquery-ui.css
- jquery-1.10.2.js
- jquery-ui.js

Answer (score 0):

To implement the reduction of the `numberOfMonths` value based on feature detection/media query, you need to use the `beforeShow` option (you can leave number of months out of the original options list as it will be redundant.

My implementation is as follows:

```
$('.date').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'm/d/yy',
    beforeShow: function() {
        if ($(window).width() < 768) {
            return { numberOfMonths: 1 };
        } else {
            return { numberOfMonths: 2 };
        }
     }
});
```